# What possible reason could SCOTUS have for taking up the Trump immunity case?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court

SCOTUS was given an opportunity several months ago to hear the appeal regarding whether Donald Trump has immunity from prosecution for actions he took while he was President. They declined to hear it, referring it to the Court of Appeals. The CoA unanimously ruled that he doesn't, and issued a nearly 60 page ruling explaining their decision.

Trump then appealed that decision, and last week SCOTUS agreed to take it up in April. It's expected that it may take several months after that before they issue their judgement, which will push the original case (assuming the ruling is against Trump) perilously close to the general election.

I'm giving SCOTUS the benefit of the doubt that they had a legal, rather than political, reason for agreeing to hear the case, which is why I posted here rather than Politics SE. But I really wonder what they could possibly expect to learn at this hearing that was not addressed in the previous ruling. It's hard not to be cynical and feel like they're intentionally assisting Trump's "delay, delay, delay" tactic to avoid prosecution.

Comment: While the question as asked is indeed soliciting opinions, the answer is interesting.  Perhaps you could reword the question to focus on certiorari before judgment.  In particular the change in frequency mentioned in the answer seems ... interesting, and the decision not to grant all the more interesting in light of the increase.

Comment: The question is very well suited to factual answers. There are very basic and straightforward reasons for taking the case, and for handling it the way the court did, despite good arguments for handling it differently.

Comment: Voting to reopen for the reasons noted above. Indeed. @Dalem has identified the objectively correct legal basis for the decision.

Comment: @bdb484 Not quite. Their answer explains why they referred the case to the Court of Appeals the first time, not why they granted certiorari now.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I'm not understanding your question, then. It seems like the obvious response would be that they took the case to resolve the legal questions presented on appeal.

Comment: @bdb484 AFAIK, the only "legal question" is that Trump didn't like the ruling. As I said, it's hard to imagine what new information they'd learn that isn't in the 60-page ruling from the appeals court.

Comment: The court doesn't take cases to hold a hearing or gather new information; it takes cases to review the decisions of lower courts. The legal question here is whether the lower courts made the right decisions. In that sense, a party not liking a ruling is always a valid legal question.

Comment: @bdb484 Now I wonder: if they simply disagree with the lower court's ruling, can they just overrule them immediately, without scheduling a new hearing several months later? Or do we have to go through all the motions (no pun intended)?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Certiorari after judgment

The acceptance of the appeal now is part of the normal process of appellate jurisdiction: [US District Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_district_court) -> [US Court of Appeals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_courts_of_appeals) -> [Supreme Court of the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States). Nothing unusual to see here, move along.

### 2. [Certiorari before judgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certiorari_before_judgment#:%7E:text=Certiorari%20before%20judgment%20is%20rarely,immediate%20determination%20in%20this%20Court.%22)

Cert before judgment is an extraordinary power of SCOTUS granted by statute that allows them to step in when asked by a party at any time after a case has been docketed in the appeals court and before judgment has been handed down.

Supreme Court Rule 11 states that this procedure will be followed "only upon a showing that the case is of such imperative public importance as to justify deviation from normal appellate practice and to require immediate determination in this Court."

The Special Prosecutor did so petition, and the court said no, probably because they weren't satisfied it met the Rule 11 threshold.

The Supreme Court granted certiorari before judgment only three times between 1988 and 2004, and zero times from then until February 2019. Since 2019, the court has granted certiorari before judgment in 20 cases.

Comment: "Nothing unusual to see here, move along": yet certiorari before judgment seems to have become become not-unusual, so there is a bit of tension between the beginning and end of this answer.

Comment: @phoog is this clearer; I’m talking about two different things

Comment: I think it could well be argued that election timeline made this case as worthy of CbJ as any of the cases they granted in the past five years.

Comment: This explains why they didn't take it up immediately, but instead referred to the Appeals Court -- CbJ is an exceptional action. But not why they then agreed to take it up now. But I guess that can only be speculation. But not justifying their action is one of the reasons SCOTUS has such a low approval rating these days.

Answer (score 0):

As described by Tejas N. Narechania in *[Certiorari in Important Cases](https://columbialawreview.org/content/certiorari-in-important-cases/)* (2022) Columbia Law Review:

> the Court grants certiorari in cases it deems sufficiently “important” — important for whatever reason — to merit review. Here, the Court’s discretion is at its apex: It is under no duty (real or imagined) to hear these cases to ensure uniformity. Instead, the Court grants review in these cases for its own rea­sons — it is free to decide which precedents to revisit, which new circum­stances to confront, and which errors to correct.

The Court does not generally provide reasons for granting certiorari, and it did not provide reasons in this case.

Therefore, we are in no better position than you to guess about why it granted certiorari.